# PDF file stored as BLOB, view in a webpage perl

Tags: perl, oracle10g

I have a code that handles displaying a blob from a local Oracle database. I store both JPG and PDF files as blob. I could view the JPG file, but not the PDF. I have checked these

```
$self->content_type('image/jpg')
```

to

```
$self->content_type('application/pdf').
```

And the Blob does have data. I checked the length and it has "184546". 
All I get when I click the link for the pdf file is a blank page with the title GETIMAGPAGE(application/pdf).

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Also, How can we have the content_type to enable two different mime_types? For example in my case both image as well as pdf, depending on what we get?

Comment: Can you look at the complete headers of your page? Use Firebug or something similar and check that the correct header is being sent. You cannot have two content types. HTTP does not support that.

Comment: With Firebug, Header has the content_type as application/pdf.

Answer (score 0):

[File::MMagic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-MMagic/MMagic.pm) can recognize the type of data using [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files).

```
use File::MMagic;
$magic = File::MMagic->new;
$self->content($blob);
$self->content_type($magic->checktype_contents($blob));
```

If you don't want to require a native/plugin PDF reader, perhaps [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/) might fit your needs.